# How much does a taxi from Lisbon airport to city center cost?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, portugal, lisbon, lis

I'm arriving in Lisbon fairly late on a Sunday with a fair amount of baggage. I've usually used the Aerobus (which works fine) but I've got more baggage than usual and it'll have been a long day by the time I get to Lisbon. So I'm looking at what a taxi is going to cost.

The [Lisbon airport site says](http://www.lisbon-airport.com/transportation.html) that it should be about 10 euros. Which would be fine. But when I follow the link they provide to an online taxi booking site, it quotes 32 euros, which is less fine. Is the airport site simply way out of date or is the booking site overcharging?

What should I expect to pay, approximately, to get to a hotel in the city center (near Marquês Pombal in my case)?

Comment: How much did you pay? :)

Comment: @Sergio Unfortunately my luggage did not make the connection in AMS with me. So without any luggage to deal with, I took the bus. Fortunately, my luggage did catch up with me the following day but I guess I won't be finding out the price of that taxi ride firsthand.

Comment: Well, it will be usefull for others... nice that the luggage showed up at least :)

Comment: Using Uber is far less complicated. It is pretty consistent taxi drivers not turning on the meter for getting a couple more euros with locals, or charging absurdities like as much as 30-50 euros to foreign people.

Comment: My only one time bad experience with Taxi in Lisbon:got to thr aiport, just took one, without luggage, I sat in, the ride was 10 minutes to the near of Benfica's Stadium. We got to the hotel, and the Taxi driver said 19.20 Euros. I said that can't be possible, he showed me a table with that fix price, and told me that that car was more expensive because it was a bigger one. I just stepped in the first taxi they gave me in the taxis queue. So this happened yesterday and I am still angry about this rip off. Uber would have costed between 6 and 8 Euros. I really do not understand this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should expect something between 9 - 15€, more than that is suspicious/wrong.

I am from Lisbon and live in Sweden now. When Traveling home I take the taxi from the Airport out to Oeiras (on the suburbs and also a extra taxed ride since it's outside Lisbon Municipality). It costs me between 25-30€.

The Lisbon airport site you named is not the official one. [www.ana.pt](http://www.ana.pt/en-US/Aeroportos/lisboa/Lisboa/Pages/HomeLisboa.aspx) is.

Check also [**this**](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw-r694Xi8ecZTc2Sk0tU2VRQlc0empJVmlFQjItQQ/edit?pli=1#) about different rates at different days/times, and [**this**](http://www.lisbonlx.com/en/transports.html) unofficial site with some info also.

You can also go to the Tourist office inside the Airport and buy a fixed price ride. 19.20€ was the price I found for weekends.

Answer (score 6):

We got a cab from the airport to the city for 12 Euro we gave him 15 as we were happy after reading all the horror stories before coming here.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for pulling this up and adding an actual current answer.

Comment: The average is between 9 to 12 euros. More than 15 and you are being taken for a fool.

Answer (score 4):

The 10€ figure meshes with my memory as well as [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lisbon#Getting_from.2Fto_the_airport). It should be a little less during daytime, perhaps a little more with a luggage or night-time surcharge. Wikivoyage also mentions a 18€ voucher which should be higher than the real rate.

Taxis are legally required to have fares posted and to have a working meter. If in doubt, ask the driver for a ballpark amount first.

There are dishonest taxi drivers in Lisbon (like anywhere else I imagine). The rate you were quoted is a lot higher than the market rate and seems to be intended to surcharge unaware visitors.

Comment: As a local I already had my share of taxi drivers not turning on the meter...more than once, and just to charge more 2 or 3 Euros, as I am a local. Nowadays I do not bother and go Uber. My wife used to work in a B&B and they were constantly threatening taxi drivers with police due to the (many) situations of them trying to overcharge guests to the tune of 30 to 50 Euros. They also go to great lengths to not give you a legal receipt if you are a foreign, often writing silly things on worthless papers to pocket the taxes, and that can cause you actual problems if your company is reimbursing you.

Answer (score 1):

be careful when arriving in Lisbon. Take Care of your belongs. Very often when people distract a bit to buy a bottle of water or a coffee they have their belongs stolen at the airport.
Be careful with taxi drivers specially with the oficial taxis you get at the airport. They will do their best to cheat you. For instance today a friend got a táxi at the airport to the Camp o Grande station. The táxi driver fixed the price before and charged him 15 euros. This journey shouldnt cost more than 6 or 7 euros. 
In another time they tried to charge me 10 euros besides the final price showed on screen, arguing that was a busy day and they coldnt do short trips. So, because my trip was short he Said he had the right to charge me 10 euros extra. Luckly I knew That was a trick and I didnt paid. Unfortunatly many tourists a victims of this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative : take an Uber. They pick up in the arrivals area. Price is about the same (10-15 Euro depending on where you go and traffic) but there is zero risk of fraud and it is much easier to pay (for someone with limited language and Euro experience).

Comment: As a local, this is the right answer IMO. Taxi drivers in the airport take pride on going out of their way to scam people.

Answer (score 1):

Just Paid €12.60 Airport to the old City using My Taxi.